Oracle 23AI cannot connect to database as newly created user
I installed Oracle 23AI free database and I'm attempting to create a new user and connect to the database as that user.  I'm using Sql Developer to connect to the database.  After connecting to the database as Sys, I run the following commands:
alter session set container = FREEPDB1;
Create User newuser identified by password1;
grant connect to newuser;
Grant create session to newuser;

All grants respond with grant succeeded.
When I attempt to connect as newuser I get the error:
Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid credential or not authorized; logon denied
I've tried granting DB_DEVELOPER_ROLE after viewing a video I found on UTube, but still cannot connect as newuser.  What am I doing wrong?

Have you define default tablespace?

Default tablespace is USERS, temporary tablespace is TEMP.  I will add that when I query the database for the roles and privileges assigned to newuser, no rows are returned.  Yet grants respond with SUCCEEDED.  I'm baffled.

From my environment (oracle free docker + MacOS):
sqlplus sys/Welcome_#1@localhost/FREE as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Dec 3 20:08:04 2024
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 23ai Free Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Develop, Learn, and Run for Free
Version 23.5.0.24.07

sys@FREE> alter session set container = FREEPDB1;

Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
[200~CreatCreate User newuser identified as password1;
Create User newuser identified as password1
                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00924: missing BY keyword


Elapsed: 00:00:00.05
sys@FREE> Create User newuser identified by password1;

User created.

sys@FREE> grant connect to newuser;

Grant succeeded.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
sys@FREE> Grant create session to newuser;

Grant succeeded.

sqlplus newuser/password1@localhost/FREEPDB1

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Dec 3 20:10:06 2024
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 23ai Free Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Develop, Learn, and Run for Free
Version 23.5.0.24.07

newuser@FREEPDB1>
newuser@FREEPDB1> @whoami
USER is "NEWUSER"

You need 'identified by' instead of 'identified as'.
Side note:

The DB_DEVELOPER_ROLE is the new role for database development in 23ai. That is the one to go with.
As an Oracle developer you operate on the pluggable database level - 'FREEPDB1'. Postgres has the 'create database' construct, Oracle Database has the 'create pluggable database' construct. A pluggable database is self-contained and can be plugged out of 'FREE' (container database) running on one host and plugged in on another 'FREE' (container database) running on another host. It is pretty cool.

Best of luck!

Opps, a copy and paste error, I actually did use identified by, not identified as.  I'm using Sql Developer, not SQLPlus.

Well, in troubleshooting mode, CLI (sqlplus or sql) is the way forward where you can have input - output documented in the terminal. And it is reproducible. That always helps in scenarios like this.
